# Instead of using $post, how do i get the thumbnail image of the $post

Tags: functions, urls

Instead of using $post, how do i get the thumbnail image of the $post

I tried using:

```
$post->link
$post->ID
$post->pw_link_target
$post->image_link 
$post ->image_id
$post->thumbnail
$post->image_url
$post_id
$id
$_GET['$post']
```

these all just go to the link of the $post, 
I just wanted to get the image of the $post

Answer (score 0):

To grab the img tag as a variable:

```
get_the_post_thumbnail ( int $post_id = null, string|array $size = 'post-thumbnail', string|array $attr = '' )
```

or if you want to outright echo it:

```
the_post_thumbnail ( string|array $size = 'post-thumbnail', string|array $attr = '' )
```

Most things like the post content, excerpt, title etc, are acquired using functions like this so that filters and hooks can be used. I'd recommend you use the `get_` versions rather than the `the_` versions, so that proper escaping and sanitisation can be applied

Further reading:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/